# Equivalent to Environment.NewLine something like Environment.RemoveLine()

Tags: c#

Is there some equivalent to Environment.NewLine  something like Environment.RemoveLine(), which will remove an entire line(text, Word...) instead of adding  a new line  ?

Comment: [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static string, on windows it is simply `string NewLine = "\r\n";`. You can't add a string to a text file that ends up removing a line. Text readers will visually show a new line when they encounter `\r\n` characters. If you want to remove a line, you need to remove the bytes of all characters that make up the line from the file itself.

Comment: Do you just want to remove the linebreak or the entire contents of a line? Also how would you want it to work for multiline content (eg if I have a string that has four lines how would I choose which line to remove?). I think the simple answer is that there isn't but if you state more exactly what your problem is we may be able to help...

Comment: `Environment.NewLine' is just a string. Do you want to just remove the NewLine characters?

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. **Environment.NewLine** is just a constant that lets you refer to the **new line** symbol on different platforms in a uniform way. How do you expect **Environment.RemoveLine()** to look like? What should it's signature and logic be?

Comment: The idea behind this is, that I have string to be set in word document depending  on the content it shall remove the current line or add a line, because otherwise there will be a gap between two line, and I dont want that gap...or maybe there is some function inside of word(some `if` follwed by some sunction which will remove that line(no vba) ?

Comment: What does current line mean in this context? That only makes sense to me if you are going through lines one at a time and if that's the case then you can just not add the line to the word document. Are you just wanting to remove empty lines (ie when you have multiple consecutive newlines)? Its still pretty unclear to me what you are trying to do...

Comment: @Chris I have a string something like this `string myString=somevalue==null ? "Sometext"+Environment.NewLine() : Environment.RemoveLine()` this string will be inserted into syncfusion(library for word documents) and will replace a placeholder in a word document. At the moment I have an empty line in my word document, `Environment.RemoveLine()` should be something like backspace ... something I can easylie pass in my string, whichh will be generally known by word, some "command"/"character" which will word to force to remove that empty line

Comment: Ah. Well in that case other people's comments are correct. There are no characters that you can use that will delete other content. The only thing that might work is if your placeholder included the linebreak and you could replace it with nothing which would, in the process remove the linebreak that is part of the placeholder.

Comment: @Chris maybe there is some condition and function I can use, if the string is empty than remove line ?!( I actually have the word file and the flace holder ist just a special formatted string in a word document)

Comment: I've not done any programatic stuff with Word so no idea what its API is like. I'm sure there is something you can do but it will be you making calls to modify the word document and not a magic pill on the Environment class.

Answer (score -1):

No, and for good reason. A space is a character like any other, as is a carriage return.  When dealing with the `string` datatype, it would be adding the responsibility of understanding what a human considers a "word" to the `Environment` class.   Since defining where you'd `Split()` a `string` to determine a word is entirely arbitrary (could be a `string` of numbers, for instance), it falls to the developer to write a class to perform this task on their own, tailored to the needs of the application.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to identify a new line in a string and then remove it, you can use the replace method.

```
var text = string.Format("Below is a new line{0}Above is a new line", Environment.NewLine);
```

View in text viewer and you can see the texts stacked

Below is a new line

Above is a new line

the use

```
text = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

and the line is removed.

If you're trying to remove whole lines of words from a paragraph e.g.

line 1 : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

line 2 : yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

line 3 : zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

and you want to remove line 2 then your 1st task is to identify the line terminator for each line of text. Removing that should move the subsequent line onto the previous.