# Function in Word (removing a line if some conditions are fulfilled)

Tags: ms-word

Is there a function which will allow me if, some string(based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878112/equivalent-to-environment-newline-something-like-environment-removeline) post) is empty to remove the entire line ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you literally want to do this in MS Word and not some sort of code/script (based on the tags provided), the only thing close would be the following key combination:

```
Home > Shift + Down > Delete
```

If you're looking for a macro in `ms-word` try this:

```
Selection.MoveDown wdLine
Selection.Expand wdLine
Selection.Delete
```